# setAutoresizingMask programmatically issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad

I have a `UIView` created on the Interface builder and I add another `UIView` (a chart) as subview which I create programatically. I played a little bit around with the iOS custom transitions but the subview does not change as it should even though an `autoresizingMask` is being used.
This is the mask I am using:

```
#define UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleMargins \
UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | \
UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin | \
UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth
```

but this is the result:
[image]
*original*

[image]

*after the transitions*

It looks like the chart doesn't respond to the transition. How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create the view, set it up so the frame's width is the width of the view (assuming that's what you want), and simply add flexible width, and the view should shrink/grow according to the size of the superview.

```
UIView *yourView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, CGRectGetWidth(self.view.frame), height)];
yourView.autoResizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
```

Comment: I'm initialising it like this chartView = [[ChartView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.chartViewHolder.frame.size.width,                                       self.chartViewHolder.frame.size.height) where chatViewHolder is the IB uiview so I don't get what is wrong

Comment: Did you set the resizing mask to simply flexible width?

Comment: I set it to UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleMargins (I define it as shown on top)

Comment: You don't want that. You want the margins to remain the same, and the width to change.

Comment: Try this, don't add the graph view to the container, set the background color on the container to something with contrast, and see if the container properly resizes. If the chatViewHolder is not sizing properly, the subview won't either.

Comment: good thought and the container view resizes the chart view remains the same

Comment: How to do you add the chart to the container?

Comment: man your idea just saved me a days work. a subview from the chartView wasn't resizing and I had to add a mask to it. I thought that setting autoresize subviews would do the trick but apparently it doesn't

Answer (score 0):

If you have correctly set up the mask as you say, and the view doesn't resize itself,
it means that you are also using `AutoLayout`. In this case it can block the **autoresizing mask**.

Go on the **`nib` property** (inspector) and disable `autolayout` (or adjust it).

Comment: I am no using the autolayout

Comment: Perfect. It is no your case. Anyway it can be the case of many other, that could be useful this answer.